# Angular Directive: use $watch or pass in binded value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller which calls a service returning a list of courses.
Each course has an property called 'percentageDone'

I want to assign some CSS to my div depending on this value.

there are 2 ways I have found to do this.  There are probably more, I am a newbie at Angular.  Thing is I am not sure what is the best way.  In terms of performance and general best Angular practice.  I realize I could use ng-class, but I am using this exercise to learn Angular.

So my Div

```
<div ng-repeat="e in courses">
  <div completion-color="{{e.percentageDone}}"></div>
</div>
```

with this directive

```
myApp.directive('completionColor', function () {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
    var donePerc = attrs['completionColor'];
     if (donePerc < 33) {
      el.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
     }
     else if (donePerc >= 33 && newVal < 66) {
      el.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
     }
     else if (donePerc >= 66) {
      el.addClass('progress-bar-success');
     }
   }
  };
});
```

or another way

```
<div completion-color="e.percentageDone"></div>
```

and js

```
myApp.directive('completionColor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs['completionColor'], function (newVal) {
                if (newVal < 33) {
                    el.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
                }
                else if (newVal >= 33 && newVal < 66) {
                    el.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
                }
                else if (newVal >= 66) {
                    el.addClass('progress-bar-success');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I like that I don't have to put the {{}} in my directive, but in general the data will not change much.  So not sure I need to use a $.watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say `$watch` is the last thing you should use here.

I myself see no problem with using `{{}}`, that's what they are for. But you have another option if you want, you could use **One Time Binding** (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) if you're using angular 1.3.X and that way you're improving performance, since angular doesn't keep watch for that:

```
<div ng-repeat="e in courses">
  <div completion-color="{{::e.percentageDone}}"></div>
</div>
```

And work with a scope in your directive (you can use isolated as well):

```
scope: {
    completionColor: "@"
},
```

Now you can use `scope.completionColor` in your link function.

Comment: thanks.  Eventually I may hook up a realtime update of this value.  Initially 1 way binding maybe fine.  If I did use the scope.$watch(attr.completionColor) does that add another watch beside the one on the e.percentageDone that is in the controller

Comment: Yes, you'll then have one extra watch in the directive.

Comment: Ok, I find this a bit odd as well, as I already have a watch in the HTML {{e.percentageDone}}, so basically I am adding another watch on the same variable.  Is there some way to reuse the same watch that is binded in the HTML

Comment: Well, if the data might change dynamically and you need to act on it I guess you have to keep this extra watch.